# Jupyter Notebook Password Hash coming out strange?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am following guides here: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html to generate a hashed password to copy into a jupyter_notebook_config.py. However, whenever I try to login to the actual Jupyter notebook, the password is not working.

This is the code I am using:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
passwd()
```

What I get in return is a hash that looks something like this: `'argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=10240,t=10,p=8$xde6DK/DQXdwQw7pviv33A$QEQftsyWij4g7oQqJ54XeQ'`

however all the passwords that I see in examples look something like this: `'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'`

What is going wrong? Also am I supposed to login with the password prehash or posthash?

Comment: `argon2` is a much _better_ password hashing format than a salted sha. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2 for background.

Comment: ...and the whole point of hashing a password is so the server is storing something that can't be used as the password itself, and from which the password can't be easily derived; so you use the pre-hash, original value to log in. If the post-hash value could be used to log in, the entire point of storing passwords in hashed form would be defeated.

Comment: Beyond that... really, this is a question about dependency chains and comparing specific versions. If one version of `notebook.auth` supports argon2 and another doesn't, you can't be installing a hash created by the newer version in an installation that only supports the older format; but the question right now doesn't contain any version details at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you so much for your detailed response. I believe the versioning may be the problem, and that is why it isn't working. Thank you. 

I also noticed that the website entered a ```u``` before their hash, as in here: ```c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'``` do you know why they put this?

Comment: `u''` is the Python 2 version of a Unicode string, which in Python 3 is just `''`. (What was `''` in Python 2 is `b''` in Python 3).

Comment: what versions of jupyter supports the new argon2 password hash?

Answer (score 0):

[Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) is a more modern, and generally stronger, password-hashing algorithm than salted sha1. It's thus a reasonable choice for current versions of Jupyter to use.

If you have one Jupyter installation that generates argon2 password hashes, and a second one that *refuses to accept* those hashes, the conclusion that follows is that there's a version difference between them.

Ideally, update the installation that isn't accepting the passwords to run the newer software release. If that isn't an option, generate your password with the same release that you need to be compatible with.

Comment: what versions of jupyter supports the new argon2 password hash?

Answer (score 0):

I found the default Argon2 didn't work in my environment (docker python 3.8, notebook=6.4.12)

Instead, specifing sha256 did the trick:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
hashed_password = passwd(passphrase='makeithapp', algorithm='sha256')

print(hashed_password)
```

[out] sha256:34bfd2bca844:a76de343d78bd11885ead698fb25b5368c08244d900f2962353c86783f31a5f2

added the following line to jupyter_notebook_config.py:

```
c.NotebookApp.password = 'sha256:b84b935d685b:8483354e8112645a9eeae9f97ed42c071b7c59ed6db8fe9d1dfc987eec636d4f'"
```

or pass the password when running the server

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root --no-browser --ip='0.0.0.0' --NotebookApp.password='sha256:b84b935d685b:8483354e8112645a9eeae9f97ed42c071b7c59ed6db8fe9d1dfc987eec636d4f'
```